# c/c++ joining processes?

Tags: c, process

I am new to threads and processes.

I have code that works fine right now with forking the code into multiple processes.  However each process needs to add to a global variable, but from what I read, each time the process forks, it takes a copy of the global, and adds them independently.  Is there a way to join them, like you can with threads?

Comment: You have to dig into inter-process communication.

Comment: You really should be using threads for this. And `fork` *should* (matter of opinion) be considered deprecated, especially since you can only perform async-signal-safe functions after `fork` in a multithreaded program and there's no testable way to determine that a program is not multithreaded (even internal parts of the implementation could be multithreaded without you knowing it).

Comment: @R.: Precisely because of the issue you've raised, a POSIX conforming implementation has to at least behave as if the internal parts of the implementation aren't multithreaded.

Comment: @caf: This would be nice, but I can't find anywhere such a requirement is stated...

Comment: fork is far from being deprecated. When requiring true separate memory etc. it is a good way to let the operating system handle the encapsulation. forking away also has the benefit that if one part of the program crashes the other parts can continue running. But right, if you need shared resources, threads can be a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different processes can communicate and exchange data via shared memory.
On linux, you can look:

> man shm_overview

for attaching a memory segment on several processes

and

> man sem_overview
>   for the semaphore library for controlling parallel access.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a struct with two fields, one for your global and one for a semaphore. Then, before any forking occurs, create some shared memory in the parent process big enough to hold this struct and initialize one there. In the children, map in the shared memory so they can access the global. All processes, parent and children, should obey the rules of the semaphore when accessing the global.

To avoid unnecessary blocking which can hurt performance, try not to hold the semaphore too long. When reading the global, make a quick copy of it in a process and use that, rather than holding the semaphore for the entire time you are using its value. Likewise, when changing the global, prepare your changes ahead of time (before you grab the semaphore) and, once you have the semaphore, copy them in all at once. Sometimes your work depends on reading and writing the global without it changing in between being read and written. In this case, some blocking may be inevitable.

It is not clear what platform you are on, but all major PC and server platforms (Windows, Linux/Unix/Mac OS) have support for shared memory and semaphores. The APIs may be different, but the functionality you need is there.